# TypeError: g is null in Datatables

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using ajax datatables in my project but I am getting g is null error in console.
The datatable actually renders fine. But because of this error, my other javascript events on that page stops working.

I read other answers here already but no luck with anything. Response from server seems fine. Number of columns in response are same as in `<thead>`.

Here are some screenshots,

Html code,

[image: html code]

jquery code,

[image: jquery code]

console response,

[image: response]

Appreciate your time and help.

Comment: What is the reason behind posting code as images on a programming Q&A site? Do you post holiday pictures as ASCII? :)

Comment: @davidkonrad So that others can see exact results/responses. Is that a problem ?

Comment: no - not for me :)

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason for this problem today.
`$(this).attr('data-path')` in this line, on initialization `this` holds the instance of table. But after the data is loaded, `this` is no more linked to table inself, rather it becomes the instance of datatable. So `$(this).attr('data-path')` will not get the attribute value of that table, and for that reason the ajax property of datatable is empty which caused this error in my case.

I still dont know how can I access the table instance instead of datatable using `this` keyword so I used directly the ID of table. `#all_students_table`.

Problem solved for now.

Thanks everyone.